# Problem with GetElementsByClass & GetElementByID

Tags: javascript, html, counter

I am working on a countdown.

I need to have multiple instances of the same item in my html.
This is my code:

```
function test() {
//                                   (AAAA,MM,DD,HH,mm,S));
var countDownDate = new Date(Date.UTC(2020,05,28,11,00,0));

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    
    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    // GMT/UTC Adjustment at the end of the function. 0 = GMT/UTC+0; 1 = GMT/UTC+1.
    var distance = countDownDate - now - (3600000 * 1);
    
    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementsByClassName("test").innerHTML = days + "<span>d</span> " + hours + "<span>h</span> "
    + minutes + "<span>m</span> " + seconds + "<span>s</span><br />";
    
    
    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("test").innerHTML = "Live <i class='fa fa-circle faa-flash animated'></i>";
    }    
}, 1000);
```

}

The problem is that when i use: `document.getElementsByClassName("test")` there is nothing in my html, but if i use: `document.getElementByID("test")` then it does work.
But I don't need to use id, because I need that element to be several times in the same html

Comment: use getElementById("test"); you have mistakes in method name

Comment: Change the elements ID to a class?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When I saw this question, it mentioned using getElementsByClassName will not get anything, the thing I can thought of if the class is added.

Really don't know why giving an votedown, it's really a basic question.

Here is the working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/t3Lc9ns6/

document.getElementsByClassName should work, it will return an HTMLCollection. Please check you HTML element if it contains the 'test' class.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('test')
```

Comment: Please give a reason for voting down.

Comment: This worked wonderfully.
Thanks for taking the time

Comment: @slowdmelendez360 np.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use className, then you need to use iteration

```
let items= document.getElementsByClassName("test");

for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
   items[i].innerHTML = `your innerHTML here`;
}
```

Comment: Should I do the same on this line? `// Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementsByClassName("test").innerHTML = days + "<span>d</span> " + hours + "<span>h</span> "
    + minutes + "<span>m</span> " + seconds + "<span>s</span><br />";`
Could you implement your code with mine?.
Thank you for helping

Comment: simply replace  `your innerHTML here`
 with 
 
`${days}d  ${hours}h  ${minutes}m  ${seconds}s <br />` edit: just to remind you dont forget `` 

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementsByClassName
```

Returns an HTML collection, which is like an array of items. You need to set the `innerHTML` of each element in the array. Try:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('test').forEach(element => element.innerHTML = "Your Code Here")
```

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('test') will return an HTMLCollection object, which doesn't contains the forEach method.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a `HTMLCollection` not a specific element, so you can't use `innerHTML` on it without getting the element first. Use iteration to loop through all items in the collection.

Also since `HTMLCollection` doesn't support simple `forEach` you may want to use `querySelectorAll` instead.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.test').forEach((element) => {element.innerHTML = "test"})
```

Answer (score 1):

The `getElementsByClassName()` method returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified class name, as an HTMLCollection object.

The HTMLCollection object represents a collection of nodes. The nodes can be accessed by index numbers. The index starts at 0

You can find out all the nodes with class name **test** by using
`Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("test"))` . Please find the code below.

```
var domElements= Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("test"));
/*For particular element*/
domElements[index].innerHTML="Your Content";
/*For all elements*/
domElements.map(element=>
{
    element.innerHTML="Your Content";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByClassName returns a collection of html elements having a specific class name as array . In your case it returns a collection of objects with class name test.

You should use above method as:
var element=document.getElementsByClassName("test");
element[0].innerHTML="Your content";

It will work!